# Can I use lets-encrypt, nginx-proxy, docker-gen and docker-compose to handle two different sub-domains?

Tags: docker-compose, lets-encrypt

Trying to get one docker instance to handle two different domains with nginx-proxy, docker-gen and lets-encrypt. When I added the new domain it stopped creating certificates and the routing (reverse-proxy) part stopped working as well. It should be possible to handle two domain, right? I just want to reuse my lets-encrypt and database for two hobby-projects and don't spend money on two droplets on digital-ocean.

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  nginx-gen:
    restart: always
    image: jwilder/docker-gen
    container_name: nginx-gen
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./volumes/proxy/templates/nginx.tmpl:/etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl:ro"
    volumes_from:
      - nginx-proxy
    entrypoint: /usr/local/bin/docker-gen -notify-sighup nginx -watch -wait 5s:30s /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

  letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:v1.4
    container_name: letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    restart: always
    volumes_from:
      - nginx-proxy
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./volumes/proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw"
    environment:
      - NGINX_DOCKER_GEN_CONTAINER=nginx-gen

  yyy_web:
    build: ../yyy/app
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - yyy_rest
    expose:
      - "80"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=yyy.noname.se
      - LETSENCRYPT_TEST=true
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=yyy.noname.se
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=<email>
      - VIRTUAL_NETWORK=nginx-proxy

  db:
    build: ../yyy/db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/lib/mongodb

  yyy_rest:
    build: ../yyy/backend
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "8080"
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=yyy_api.noname.se
      - LETSENCRYPT_TEST=true
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=yyy_api.noname.se
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=<email>
      - VIRTUAL_NETWORK=nginx-proxy


  xxx_web:
    build: ../xxx/ui
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - xxx_rest
    expose:
      - "80"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=xxx.noname.se
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=xxx.noname.se
      - LETSENCRYPT_TEST=true
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=<email>
      - VIRTUAL_NETWORK=nginx-proxy

  xxx_rest:
    build: ../xxx/service
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "8081"
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=xxx_api.noname.se
      - LETSENCRYPT_TEST=true
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=xxx_api.noname.se
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=<email>
      - VIRTUAL_NETWORK=nginx-proxy
```